# Oracle Database 11g R2 no realiza commit con replicación de streams en Amazon AWS en instancias EC2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, aws, ec2

Estoy manejando replicación por medio de streams en Oracle Database 11g R2, utilizando para esto instancias EC2 de Amazon AWS, actualmente tengo 2 instancias las cuales son el Server A y Server B, tanto la configuración como los comandos ejecutados no dan ninguna clase de error

Tengo un problema al momento de realizar un commit. La transacción es la siguiente:

```
insert into pelicula(idPelicula, nombre, director, anho) values(1, 'Deadpool', 'Tim Miller', '2016');
commit;
```

La nueva fila se agrega correctamente a la base de datos en el servidor A, pero cuando en el server B realizo una consulta

```
select * from pelicula;
```

No aparece la nueva fila que debería haberse propagado. Ni el insert ni el commit generan ninguna clase de error, así que no tengo idea porque sucederá esto.

¿De qué manera puedo comprobar alguna clase de error en la transacción?